# What keyword is used to create a customized tooltip via double clicking the word on web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, tooltip

I'm trying to mimic features from Grammarly(which shows a card including definitions by double-clicking the word). I couldn't figure out where to start.

What I want is just to make a blank block content below the selected word by dbclick the word like Grammary does.

I've tried searching the keyword such as 'tooltip, pop-up etc..' but couldn't find the single article I can look up.

Could anyone enlighten my brain please? :(

[Sample: Card Block in Grammarly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAPxn.png)

Comment: You have to use javascript pluglin like this: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Comment: @GermanoPlebani Tnx a lot! Would it be difficult I build the feature myself without using jquery plug-in?

Comment: No, but it depends on the level of sophistication you want to reach.